# Start smartcard service at startup in a raspberry pi

Tags: linux, boot

I have a raspberry pi connected to smart card reader (OMNIKEY 3121). I installed all driver and libraries needed. In order to use the card reader it is necessary to activate its service:

```
sudo systemctl start pcscd
```

I want to start the service at startup. I tried with this commands:

```
sudo su
systemctl enable pcscd
```

Last command returned this:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/pcscd.socket -> /lib/systemd/system/pcscd.socket
```

After reboot the service is inactive.

Do you know how can I enable this service at startup?

Answer (score 2):

You noted in a comment that the `pcscd` service starts another service `pcscd.socket`. You should edit the question and add this important information to it. With the command

```
rpi ~# systemctl enable pcscd
```

you have only enabled `pcscd.socket` as you can see at the link to enable the socket service:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/pcscd.socket -> /lib/systemd/system/pcscd.socket
```

You should enable the service with

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable pcscd.service
```

After reboot you can monitor the services with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status pcscd.service
rpi ~$ systemctl status pcscd.socket
rpi ~$ systemctl cat pcscd.service
rpi ~$ systemctl cat pcscd.socket
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo systemctl enable pcscd` will get it active at boot time.

Comment: I tried this with the same result, it doesn't work for me

Comment: Then you need to look at the logs to understand why it doesn't start.

Comment: After some tests I now what is happening, but I don't know why. This pcscd service starts another service named pcscd.socket. This one is active at startup and smartcard reader works. If a card is inserted at startup in the reader pcscd is active, but if there is no card at startup is it inactive.

Comment: How can I check service's logs?

Comment: Take a look at every file in /var/log - learn what gets logged there by systemd.

Answer (score 0):

Read first the question and every detail from that question before prematurely posting a pseudo-answer that is like coming from a parrot.

This is an open problem and the root cause can be found in the `C` source code of `pcsc` and in the way how it interacts with `systemd`. Read more [here](https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/PCSC/issues/70).